# ASP.NET & C# - Two values in a listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding ListItems to a ListBox from two controls, both are DropDownLists.

The ListItem has the properties ListItem.SelectedItem and ListItem.SelectedValue, but I also want the ListBox to keep track of which DropDownList the ListItem came from.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I went about solving this, was creating an ArrayList, with another array inside for each item.

Answer (score 5):

You could set the ID of the dropdown programatically as a attribute of the listitem.

```
ListItem i = new ListItem();
i.Attributes["IDofDropDown"] = "SomeID";
```

Comment: I'm not sure, are these attributes transferred between postbacks ?

Comment: Wouldn't this emit it in the html markup and make the code invalid?

Comment: @SP, I tried what you suggested via 
lstTrainers.Items[number].Attributes["TrainerType"] = "Trainer";

lstTrainers.Items[number].Attributes.Add("TrainerType", ExTrainer");

But I'm getting an attribute count of 0 when I look at the ListItem.  I'm passing the ListBox to a different object.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the `.Value` section so that its something like `DropDownList1:SomeValue` and then you can use String.Split to extract the info back out of `.SelectedValue`?

Answer (score 0):

`ListItem` item contains `Text` and `Value` properties that mapped from option element in HTML. So you can not add any other value to this structure. But maybe you can save the source dropdown's id to the `Value` of the `ListItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an in memory dataset to store all the data needed and then bind the dataset to your ListBox. When ever a value is selected you will have access to more fields in code behind.